# Negative eigenvalues of a covariance matrix

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra

I'm computing eigenvalues of a covariance matrix, and I'm getting negative eigenvalues after 100'th eigenvalue. These eigenvalues are obviously incorrect.

Is there some heuristic, or a better decomposition in Mathematica to find the list of "correct" eigenvalues in a covariance matrix decomposition? I'm using this decomposition to get a preconditioner for a larger dataset that will make it approximately spherically distributed, so I would replace the incorrect values with 0's or 1's.

Finding location of first negative eigenvalue is one such heuristic although I'm not sure if it'll hold in general. Also, I tried higher precision with `N[cov, 20]`, but Eigenvalue decomposition takes long time with no indication of when it's going to finish.

```
mnist = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh4Mq.png"],"Byte"]]]];
cov = mnist.mnist\[Transpose];
Partition[mnist[[All, 1]], 28] // ArrayPlot
plot1 = ListPlot[Log@Eigenvalues[N[cov]]];
plot2 = ListPlot[Log[-Eigenvalues[N[cov]]], 
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Tiny], Red}];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

Comment: Negative eigenvalues are perfectly acceptable.  Just plot the absolute value of them.

Comment: But it's a covariance matrix, aren't eigenvalues supposed to be all non-negative?

Comment: Ah... for a covariance matrix...yes, you're right.

Comment: Try using `cov = Transpose[mnist].mnist` instead.

Comment: I agree with bill s. Transpose postfix definitely gets me in trouble every time because it has a very low precedence and often gets evaluated after what was actually desired.

Comment: I think it does what I'm expecting it to do, on paper you write A.A' which means transpose "A" first, and that's what Mathematica does as well. @bills solution gives transpose of a different matrix, that matrix is full rank, and there's no problem with negative eigenvalues

Comment: @yode -- how did you re-encode my data into an image?

Comment: Also, somewhat off-topic, but you probably want to use the SVD on those image vectors anyway.

Comment: The reason for suggesting the transpose is precisely the dimensional argument. With mnist.Transpose[mnist] you have a 700 by 700 matrix, which contains 600 eigenvalues that are structurally all zero. With Transpose[mnist].mnist, you have only the 100 or so actual eigenvalues (and they are the same as the nonzero eigenvalues of mnist.Transpose[mnist]. As Daniel says, it is just numerical noise that is causing them to be zero.

Comment: Computing the singular values of A is the same mathematically (up to taking squares) as computing the eigenvalues of $A A^t,$ and the algorithm is much more numerically stable (so, I don't understand why Daniel Lichtblau thinks his comment is off-topic).

Comment: thanks, SVD indeed looks better for this purpose, those values are identically zero after 100

Comment: I was suggesting it as a better way to do a principal components analysis type of decomposition, without really considering it is also numerically more stable. For that latter purpose the suggestion is on topic, but maybe less so for the former (since the question did not mention PCA explicitly).